# How to use facebook test users from android

Tags: android, facebook

I need help using the facebook test users from android.I am using the facebook android sdk and i need to be able to login as a test user and do actions like publish to the stream. I do not want to use the developer account associated with this application since it is my personal account. I realize that test users can only be created using api calls and such a call returns the login url, i understand how to use this in a browser but how can i use it in my android application. Can i create a dummy account and work with that account or is this against facebook policy.

Answer (score 6):

Test users can also be created with GUI - not only by API calls. GUI is useful if You need to handle just few users. If there is a plenty of them - it is easier to use API and perform it programatically.

How to handle test users by FB GUI:

1. Go to [FB developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/), where You created FB Application
2. on [application tab](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), click Edit Roles
3. At the bottom of the page there is 'Test users' section where all test users are listed. This is where test users can be created and edited. Each user has option to log in as this user, change his name and set password next to his profile photo.
4. You have to set user's password to be able to login as him
5. Use his profile email address and password to login - it is also possible from Your app

You can create a dummy account but this is against FB policy and FB really does everything to make it harder to You :) This is not an option. Use test users.

If more info is needed on the topic - [see my article, regarding test users strategy](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/facebook-test-users/).
All the detail see on the [official FB page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/)

Comment: Love your article: "I still don’t know how to change users’ email (that is a bit hard to remember in default)." Would you mind to edit when you remember? :)

Comment: I don.t know how to change email. I don.t even have a clue that this is possible

Comment: Yeah after working almost a day with a test user account I think you're right. It's pretty limited. Think I'll put some effort in my schizophrenic personality and create a real fake account for proper testing o.O

Comment: Change user's name and surname to some simple ones. It will simplify email a bit. I do not recommend using real fake accounts. FB requires to verify each with mobile phone number or credit card number :) That limits amount of real fake users that one can verify :P

Answer (score 2):

See an open [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403919519621830/) in facebook. You can't login as test user with native Android app, but login with m.facebook.com should work

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

where the access_token is the token from when the user approved your app.  Found it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).