# Android Facebook SDK - how to send a request to a test user?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

This is actually a 2 parts question.

1. I cant figure out how to send a request to a test user using the request dialog. i was able to send it to a friend but how can i select a test user which is not part of my friends list ? from the tutorial in [Handle Request App Links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/app-link-requests/) it seems like you just need to define a Test User is the App Dashboard and he should selectable in the Send Request Dialog. what am i doing wrong here ?
2. When i checked a request sent to a friend i saw that the actual notification he is getting is "***My Name* invited you to try *App Name***". and thats it. What happened to the message and title parameters used in the Request Dialog ?

   ```
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("message", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
   params.putString("title", context.getString(R.string.app_name));

   WebDialog requestsDialog = (
       new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(context,
           Session.getActiveSession(),
           params)).build();
   ```

   are they just for the dialog itself ? if so, how disappointing it this. i hope im wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use facebook test users from android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781486/how-to-use-facebook-test-users-from-android)

Comment: This is not a duplicate ! and thanks for downvoting me.
my first question was how to use the send request dialog to send a request to test users. according to the tutorial i mentioned they suppose to be available in the send request dialog, but i cant see the one i created in the App Dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever wondered about the first part of this question (the "duplicate" one) - 
In order to send a request to a test user, you have to do it from another test user. you need to define 2 test users in the app dashboard and make them friends. then you need to login to one of them in which ever way you want and you will able to see the other one in the send request dialog.

FB tutorials are just crap.