# Is it obligatory to have test users in a Facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-test-users

I created the Facebook app, I defined actions objects etc.Do I have to test open graph with test user while the android app it is not published yet . Do I have to test it for objects actions to be approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating test users and testing app with them is optional, it is for your satisfaction and quality assurance.

Purpose of Test users is as follows:

> A test user is a special Facebook account, invisible to real accounts,
>   which can be created within an app for the purpose of manual or
>   automated testing of that app's Facebook integration.
>
> We ensure that test users are exempt from our spam and fake account
>   detection systems so that you can test your app without worrying about
>   getting disabled.

Read complete detail [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users)

See this link also:

[How to use facebook test users from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781486/how-to-use-facebook-test-users-from-android)